# React-Native: how to import / use RC experimental components, i.e. SwipeableRow (0.27 rc)?

Tags: facebook, react-native

I am wondering how to import / use / test new components in a ReactNative RC? Specifically, I want to import and use the [SwipeableRow components](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/v0.27.0-rc1/Libraries/Experimental/SwipeableRow) in [0.27.0-rc1](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.27.0-rc1). Once I can import it, I can dig around in the code base to understand the params and options, but I can't even get past the `import` step...

I have the right tagged release installed via `npm`, but when I try importing the components, they show up as `undefined`:

```
import {
  ListView,
  ScrollView,
  StyleSheet,
  SwipeableListView,
  Text,
  TouchableHighlight,
  View
  } from 'react-native';
```

I get errors like:

[image: screenshot]

Render code (that triggers the above):

```
render() {
    var ds = new SwipeableListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    blah blah blah
}
```

I have also tried moving the `SwipeableRow` folder to be a child of `Libraries` (instead of `Libraries` -> `Experimental` -> `SwipeableRow`, now it is `Libraries` -> `SwipeableRow`). Same error.

I have tried importing `Experimental` and then using `<Experimental.SwipeableRow.SwipeableListView>`, but that also throws an "Undefined is not an object" exception.

As suggested, I also tried importing by using a direct path to the node module:

```
import {
  SwipeableListView
} from '../../../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Experimental/SwipeableRow';
```

That resulted in:

```
Unable to resolve module ../../../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Experimental/SwipeableRow from <source component path>: File <path>/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Experimental/SwipeableRow/index doesnt exist
```

I then tried:

```
import {
  SwipeableListView
} from '../../../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Experimental/SwipeableRow/SwipeableListView';
```

Which resulted in:

```
Unable to resolve module emptyFunction from <path>/Libraries/Experimental/SwipeableRow/SwipeableRow.js: Unable to find this module in its module map or any of the node_modules directories under /Users/node_modules/emptyFunction and its parent directories. This might be related to github issue 4968 (paraphrasing).
```

Is there a way to use and test these experimental components? Or do I just have to wait for the official release?

Comment: That seems to fix the emptyFunction issue https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/7954

Comment: Oh, nice find @HugoDozois. I tried manually making that change locally, but I still get an error when importing SwipeableListView from react-native: "undefined is not an object (evaluating new _reactNative.SwipeableListView.getNewDataSource')"

Comment: I just tested locally and it works, so I made it as an answer so it's easy to find.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the module has a `@providesModule` annotation, it can be required directly. This is something specific to the packager used in react-native!

You can just do

```js
const SwipeableRow = require('SwipeableRow');
// or 
import SwipeableRow from 'SwipeableRow';
```

And to fix the empty function issue, just change the require to the following:

```js
const emptyFunction = require('fbjs/lib/emptyFunction');
```

while waiting for the [next version](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/7954) to come out.

Comment: Oh awesome, thanks! I guess this was mostly my ignorance with the react-native packager...but does works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Please use the documentation in the code on how to use [SwipeableRow](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/26a92220c2a6355afc0a54be4a7266da50f7c692/Libraries/Experimental/SwipeableRow).

I will work on writing documentation that is external to the code as time allows, but there is commenting in the code that should get you started.

The general way to use it is:

1. It's `let ds = SwipeableListView.getNewDataSource()`
2. Do the usual `cloneWithRowsAndSections(..)` as you would any other `ListView`, check the source of `SwipeableListView` for what params to supply
3. Use `SwipeableListView` as you would `ListView`; so same props as `ListView` with additional props described in [SwipeableListView.js](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/26a92220c2a6355afc0a54be4a7266da50f7c692/Libraries/Experimental/SwipeableRow/SwipeableListView.js). `renderRow` is the top part that is swipeable, `renderQuickActions` is the bottom part that is revealed when swiped.

Then you should use it just like you would `ListView`, i.e. something like `<SwipeableListView renderRow={..} renderQuickActions={..} {..someListViewProps} />`

That's about it.

Comment: Hi Fred, thanks for the answer! Can you please elaborate on how I import SwipeableListView in the first place? (import {???} from 'react-native'...) I can't get that import step to work -- after that, I'm happy to follow your guidance and dig into the code, to see how the components work...

Comment: @user1370384 I'm not sure, I've never done React Native development outside of work, but I will ask and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a complete newbie here, but in the code you provided, you are importing the SwipeableListView from react native. If I'm not mistaken, if you used the .js from the link you provided, you must import from your path where those .js files reside. An example of what I mean:

```
import { SwipeableListView } from './YourPathToTheJSFile';
```

I tried leaving this as a comment, because I'm not sure this is the right answer. I hope this helps.

Comment: Hm..good suggestion, but that also throws an error (possibly because that requires using the path directly to a node_module library ... which is atypical in my limited experience). I'll update the question to reflect what I tried.

Comment: Are you working with node modules or .js files? If you're working with .js files, those reside outside of your node_modules path and you would use the import syntax I suggested. If using node modules, you would npm install them, then import them as you have. The link you provided to the SwipeableListView code suggests you are using .js files. The other thing you may want to investigate is - is the SwipeableListView.js file importing its dependencies correctly and are the dependencies available or in the right location? Just some thoughts.

Comment: These components (SwipeableListView) are in the ReactNative node modules. The issue is that I cannot import via the typicall import syntax ...